# Click button and go to page section in Vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js, button

I want to implement a button that automatically scrolls to a specific `div id="contactMe"`, which is located on the same page. I am using vue.js.

I tried the following method with native js.

```
    <input
        onClick="document.getElementById('contactMe').scrollIntoView();"
        type="submit"
        class="cta-button bg-yellow mt-8 flex justify-center"
        :value="$frontmatter.contactFormButton"
      />
```

However, I receive the following error in my console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):1)

What is the right command in the vue framework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `input[type="submit"]` as it only should submit the `form`. A simple `button` would do with the correct Vue events:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    buttonText: 'Lorem'
  },
  methods: {
    scroll() {
      const element = document.getElementById('contact-me');
      element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
}

#contact-me {
  margin-top: 2000px;
  margin-bottom: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="scroll">{{ buttonText }}</button>
  
  <div id="contact-me">
    contact me box
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called [vue-scrollto](https://github.com/rigor789/vue-scrollto) which gives you a more convenient way to handle scrolling.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
  }
})
```

```css
h1, button {
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-scrollto@2.7.9/vue-scrollto.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-scroll-to="'#element'">
    Scroll to #element
  </button>
  
  <h1 id="element">Hi. I'm element</h1>
</div>
```